# Is this code from w3school correct?

Tags: javascript

i learn javascript from w3school. I got to this example. Is there any possibility how to write this code  "better" ? Is it not antiquated?

Thank You

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>JavaScript Arrays</h1>

<p>The best way to loop through an array is using a standard for loop:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var fruits, text, fLen, i;

fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fLen = fruits.length;
text = "<ul>";
for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {
    text += "<li>" + fruits[i] + "</li>";
}
text += "</ul>";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a working code...
For actions like this you can use jQuery.

Comment: sure there are many ways to write the same code but we don't know what you mean by "better". are you talking about performance or elegance?

Comment: W3Schools has nothing to do with the W3C FYI

Comment: @Liam yes You are right sorry

Comment: @SniCel note that better is a subjective term and objective of w3schools is to learn beginners. So they will have to use imperative programming. There are ways to achieve same result with less number of lines, but you should first understand basics properly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will suggest this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <h1>JavaScript Arrays</h1>

    <p>The best way to loop through an array is using a standard for loop:</p>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
      var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
      var fVar = 0;
      var fLen = fruits.length;
      var htmlContent = "<ul>";
      for (fVar = 0; fVar < fLen; fVar++) {
        htmlContent += "<li>" + fruits[fVar] + "</li>";
      }
      htmlContent += "</ul>";
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = htmlContent;
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is just a basic code to understand the Array concept nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know, if it is actually better, but in any case it is shorter and uses more "modern" features.

```
let fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"],
    text   = fruits.map( (fruit) => '<li>' + fruit + '</li>' );

document.querySelector('#demo').innerHTML = '<ul>' + text.join('') + '</ul>';
```

Comment: map ? join sounds better in this case no ? `'<ul><li>'+["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"].join('</li><li>')+'</li></ul>'`

Comment: I personally dislike joins in the way you use them there as to me it is not as structured as the code I posted. But I missed a `join()` in my code anyways, so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can create in you html

```
<ul id="fruitUl"></ul>
```

then

```
text="";
for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {
    text += "<li>" + fruits[i] + "</li>";
}
$("fruitUl").append(text);
```

this is antique too. it's just my opinion.